# How I can display the <div> 'below' the 'clicked word'

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular10

I am new user of Angular10 and I want that Whenever the user will click on any **word** in the textarea field/input field, then the **popup**  always display **below that clicked word**.

You can also have a look in attached images that what I want to implement.

Thankyou so much

The **div** that I want to dispaly on popup is following:

```
<div class="cstm-popup-div">
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.cstm-popup-div {
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -489px;
  position: absolute;
  index: 99;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If relevant post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, or code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Can you provide code to help reproduce it ? And be more precise about the place you want the popup to be

Comment: Hi @YounesGuarssifi thanks for your reply. actually I want that When the user will click on any word in the textarea then always the popup <div> will display below from that position i.e. below from the clicked word.  As you can see in the attached image for example once the user will click on 'that' word then (popup <div>) displaying below from that position. I hope understand my problem.

Comment: Hi @YounesGuarssifi, ccan you help me?